# how to get the controller inside of playframework template?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, template-engine, playframework-2.2

I used playframework2.2：

My template is:

```
@(topiclink:String, head: String, rate: Int, topicid:Int, summary: String, pic_url:String)
@if(topiclink=="Shoplist"){
<a class="list-group-item" href="@routes.ShoplistController.pagelist(topicid.toString())">
}else {
 <a class="list-group-item" href="@routes.PageController.pagelist(topicid.toString())"> 

}</a>
```

I want to write more OOP, I mean I want to use the parameter of:

```
@(topiclink:Controller, head: String, rate: Int, topicid:Int, summary: String, pic_url:String)
```

and then can directly @topiclink.pagelist(topicid.tostring())

Then I can directly get to the correspond controller pagelist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing in the controller directly is probably a bad idea - consider having the controller create objects that represent the data (pagelist) you want.

Regardless, whatever you "pass in", it's the controllers job to "pass it in" - remember all these things are parameters.  If you really want the controller, then in the controller where you create your page use the **this** keyword:

```
views.html.index.myPage(this, otherParam, ...)
```